# Cannot add handler in eclipse e4 application model since upgrading to oxygen

Tags: eclipse

I am working on an Eclipse e4 RCP application with multiple fragments/plug-ins. 
I upgraded from Neon to Oxygen and now I have the problem, that I can't add any handler or command in my fragments/plug-ins.
When trying the same in the main application.e4xmi it's no problem, but the other e4xmi-models don't have the context-menu item to add a handler to the model-fragment (also not possible in the details view of the fragment --> list to select the child is empty). 
All my previous handlers and command are there.

Am I missing some plug-in oder dependency? I only upgraded to Oxygen.

---

Added: To clarify, I did not upgrade my existing eclipse to oxygen. I installed a new Oxygen RCP-Client. Did I forget to add anything to make this work again?

---

Added Nr2:
As greg-449 proposed using the "**xpath:/**"-Expression instead of the full ID of the main e4xmi Model as a reference for the "Extenden Element ID" works when trying to reference elements on the first level of the model like commands, handerls and key bindings. 
But whe trying to use more complex expressions like for referencing the perspective stack or a toolbar this method doesn't work any more.

Comment: Works here. What do you have as the 'Extended Element ID' and 'Feature Name' for the Model-Fragment?

Comment: extended element id = id of main application.e4xmi
feature name = handlers
this setup worked with neon

Comment: Maybe try `xpath:/` as the Extended Element ID - it means the same thing as the main app id (but saves having to put the id in all the fragments)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: when using xpath on the first level, for handlers, commands or bindings it works perfectly. But when using more complex xpath-expressions it's not working any more, like getting the main toolbar in the top trimbar. I trief the following: //trimBars/*[1] but it won't work. Also when trying to reference the perspective stack with //children[@*[local-name()='type' and .='advanced:PerspectiveStack']].

Comment: I have only ever used xpath:/ I don't any more than is mentioned in the [vogella article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Modularity/article.html)

Comment: I have the same problems. After the first klick on Model Fragment the Eclipse is freezing for 10s or more..  Then the List is empty. I think this shoud be reported as a bug? Maybe fill the List with all elements when there is no match to the given id in the fragments plugin